# portable GAE bigtable abstraction for python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bigtable

I am designing a new GAE python application and would like to design it in a way to allow self-hosting.

A lot of web frameworks are platform neutral, but when it comes to database, I have a very hard time finding any NoSql abstraction that would work on GAE and something (anything) else.

The only solutions I see:

AppScale http://code.google.com/p/appscale/ :
a virtualmachine that emulates the datastore API's.  The biggest issue is the need of a virtual machine, so only suitable for ultra-big enterprise level development.  This is probably the best solution though.....

Django-norel http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel :
some GAE specific weirdness, but seems manageable.   the main drawback is being forced to use django, (I am inclined towards pyramid)

**So my question:** are there any other potential solutions?  a "light" abstraction allowing retargeting from bigtable to, say couchdb or another nosql database would be ideal.

PS: I know i could use Google cloud-sql (hosted mysql instance) but I'm looking to focus on nosql.

Comment: Why doesn't the datastore fulfill your requirements?

Comment: the GAE datastore does fulfill my usage requirements, however i sometimes am asked to do outsourcing by a government agency that requires a stand-alone server (no external access) so I would like to have only 1 way of coding the database, not needing a different way just to satisfy the infrastructure needs of a client.

Comment: It's 2012 and virtual machines are not "ultra-big enterprise level". I'm having a couple just for private use. I'm sure your enterprise/government customer already has a hired/owned VM farm. If not see http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/top-vps-providers/

Comment: thanks for the feedback peter, however my gov customer does not have a VM farm and they don't allow use of external servers (I'm in Thailand FYI, which may be a bit behind the times).

so yeah, i'd have to setup a vm server and all the infrastructure/maintenence complexities that entails (I use cloud to get away from that stuff so I'm not enthusiastic about going back)

Comment: @jaysun At any point, you will need to setup a server your application can access. Setting up Appscale is no different, but if you are just looking for some easy way to store, you might want to try this key-value store, its not yet finished but you can get the idea: http://www.ohloh.net/p/whopper

Comment: @jaysun At any point, you will need to setup a server your application can access. Setting up Appscale is no different, but if you are just looking for some easy way to store, you might want to try this key-value store, its not yet finished but you can get the idea: http://www.ohloh.net/p/whopper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) includes a [MongoDB stub](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/source/browse/src/typhoonae/mongodb/datastore_mongo_stub.py) for the datastore and the official SDK includes a [SQLlite stub](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_sqlite_stub.py)

Comment: hey that's great, i didn't know the gae sdk had that.   seems pretty like what i need!  I'll check it out.